# Elision with si + il

Tags: grammaire, orthographe

Is there **always** elision with si +il ?
I recently saw the following sentence written:

> Personne ne m'en voudrait si il me prenait l'envie de vouloir noyer mon chagrin.

I was sure that si + il would make s'il.
Is it still correct to write it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not always elision.

While in written form, ***s'il*** is by far the most common, you'll more often hear a longer  `/si:l/`, an elided  `/si i/`, or both `/si:/`.

Answer (score -2):

L'élision est presque toujours  faite de nos jours, mais il n'est toujours pas incorrect de ne pas la faire. Il était encore courant au 19<sup>e</sup> de ne pas utiliser cette élision. Cela peut être constaté dans le ngram suivant et la page d'exemples qui correspond.

[image]

[si il](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22si%20il%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)